# ignoring a part of a string in find_all in beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extact all the urls from [this](http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/) webpage.

The python code I am using is this

```
htmlfile=urllib.urlopen("http://dubai.dubizzle.com/property-for-rent/residential/apartmentflat/").read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlfile)

link=soup.find_all('a', xtclib="listing_list_1_title_link", href=True)

for a in link:
    print a['href'],'\b'
```

but it extracts urls with xtclib = "listing_list_1_title_link" only. How can I make the expression like xtclib = "listing_list_(any number here)_title_link"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a compiled regular expression object:

```
import re

...

link=soup.find_all(
    'a',
    xtclib=re.compile(r"listing_list_\d+_title_link"),
    href=True)
```

See [Beautiful Soup Documentation - Regular Expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression).

Comment: thanks alot. it works. Few more questions please
1. How do i learn these basic regular expressions for decimals and strings etc. can u please share some basic website for learn them

2. What is this "r" in the start of the re.compile statement. If omitted it and it still works

Comment: @AhmedMukhtar, 1. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html  2. It's raw string literal. Using it you don't need to escape backslash to represent literal backslash.  If this answer was helpful, please accept the answer.

Comment: You don't need to escape \d, but it's better to explicitly escape it (or use raw string literal as the answer). But for letters that have special meaning (for example, \n. \t. ...), escaping is mandatory.

Comment: Can someone do the same thing with soup.select method?

Comment: @AhmedMukhtar, You can't do that. `select` methods accept css selector, not regular expression. See [BeautifulSoup Documentation - CSS Selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).